# Controlgroup in panel seems not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, menu, panel

I'm developing an app with JQM. I want to use a controgroup in a panel as menu but it is not working a I expect...

See the jsfiddle here > click on the gear button at left top: http://jsfiddle.net/japx5xxh/

How to delete margin on the top and bottom of the buttons?

HTML:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="home-options" data-display="overlay" class="ui-mini ui-panel-inner">
    <div data-role="control group">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">No icon</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left">Left</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-right">Right</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-panel-inner { 
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Thank you a lot!

Comment: `&nbsp;` has been added between anchors, remove them and remove class ` ui-panel-inner` from panel div, it will be added dynamically and will wrap contents. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/japx5xxh/1/

Comment: Indeed. Thank you. Additional question: do you know how to delete the rounded corner of the buttons? I have deleted `ui-corner-all` but it doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/japx5xxh/3/

Comment: Try `data-corners="false"` added to controlgroup div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Omar, the problem was coming from `&nbsp;` that were added by my text editor for an unknown reason between the control group elements.